# Doing topological sort using strongly connected components to find cycles (digraph)

Tags: algorithm, topological-sort, connected-components

From the little I understand, one way of doing topological sorting if you have a readymade efficient black-box method for strongly connected components would be:

(assumption - no self loops)

1. run strongly connected components
2. if you have one or more components of size > 1 then this graph has cycles.
3. else (there are only 1 sized components in the graph) it's a DAG, congrats!
4. if it's a DAG run topological sort, else complain that you can't do it.

Regardless of efficiency, is the above a "technically correct" way to do topological sorting?

I just want to make sure I understand things correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's technically correct, because a digraph without self-loops is acyclic (i.e., topologically sortable) iff all strong components have size 1. The most common topological sorts do cycle detection as an easy byproduct, though.

Comment: Great, thanks! Is there a reference book / web page with a "cheat sheet" of those propositions? (e.g. like the "a digraph without self-loops is acyclic iff all strong components have size 1") I mean, all algorithm books / resources teach you the algorithms, but leaves you to kind of think for yourself on all those relations between them. Is there anything like this? Thanks again

Comment: @EranMedan Probably not, since there are way too many of them. This one in particular has a proof of just a few lines: if there's a cycle, it has at least two vertices (no self-loops), which have paths to one another and thus belong to the same strong component, which has size at least 2; if there's a strong component of size at least 2, then there's a cycle that consists of concatenating the paths from one vertex to the other.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the answer above: yes, the algorithm you presented above is correct and will product the answer that you want. A topological sort only works with a DAG (directed acyclic graphs). SCC are a set of vertexes in which every vertex can reach every other vertex and is cyclic in nature. Thus, a DAG should have V # of SCC components of size 1.

However, there are a number of redundancies in the algorithm as the SCC algorithm is usually implemented using DFS with a run time of O(V + E) which may approach O(V^2) depending on how your data is stored and the density of the graph. Generating all the SCC and looking to through all vertices to check if they exist in a SCC size > 1 generates O(2V + E) which is really still just O(V + E), but you end up needing extra storage of Θ(V) for the SCC.

Additionally, topological sort also utilizes DFS which can detect cycles and thus can signal whether a topological sort is possible. This also runs in O(V + E). Thus you can simply just run a topological sort without having to utilize a SCC algorithm as well. While the overall big O of your algorithm is the same as the running time of a topological sort, there is no need to run SCC as it does not give you any extra useful information.